# NodejS Read/Write Binary Data to/from file

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, stream, binary

Alright, so I have a string with binary data ("111011 10001 etc"), and I'm trying to save it to a file to them read it on another file using streams, the issue is that, the stream is cutting the data off (final binary number in chunk is cut off)[image]

This is how I'm sending the data to the file (reading a file, encoding it with the golombRice encoder and storing it in a file, using chunks of data)

```
  const writer = fs.createWriteStream(
    `./encodedAndDecoded/encoded${filename}`,
    {
      encoding: "binary",
    }
  );
  const reader = fs.createReadStream(`./silesia/${filename}`, {
    encoding: "base64",
  });

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.on("data", (chunk) => {
      writer.write(Buffer.from(golombRiceEncoding(chunk, 3)));
    });
    reader.on("end", () => {
      writer.end();
      resolve();
    });
  });
```

This is how I'm reading it (reading the encoded file, decoding it with the golombRice encoder and storing it in a file, using chunks of data, the issue with this is that the chunks don't have the full binary data because the stream cuts it)

```
  const writer = fs.createWriteStream(`./encodedAndDecoded/decoded${filename}`);

  const reader = fs.createReadStream(`./encodedAndDecoded/encoded${filename}`, {
    encoding: "binary",
  });

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.on("data", (chunk) => {
      writer.write(Buffer.from(golombRiceDecoding(chunk, 3), "base64"));
    });
    reader.on("end", () => {
      writer.end();
      resolve();
    });
  });
```

Wonder if there's a way to make it read the data using streams, but without cutting a binary number? I don't mind if it reads x at a time, the issue is when it cuts a binary number, invalidating the data when decoding.
Thank you

Comment: To read data from a file and decode it, you HAVE to decode it intelligently by knowing where meaningful boundaries of chunks are.  If your encoding is not just single bytes, but involves groups of bytes, then you can't decode it by arbitrary chunks of data.  You have to decode a chunk that breaks on a boundary that makes sense for your decoding.  So, this problem is specific to your encoding and how it works.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to set those boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

Your particular compression scheme that you're trying to decode looks like it's a variable byte scheme.  So, if a chunk boundary doesn't perfectly line up with the size of a variable byte piece of compression, your decompression library  will fail.

To decode something like this on the fly, you have to build logic right into the decoder that recognizes when it only has a partial piece of data and then buffers that to combine it with the next chunk of data that arrives.  Because the compression is variable byte, you can't known where proper boundaries are without being part of the decompression logic.

Or, you can give up doing on-the-fly decoding and buffer all the compressed data into memory and then decompress it all at once when you have all the data (then you don't have any chunk boundaries to worry about).

Comment: Yes this was exacly what I am currently trying to do, adding logic to the encoder to recognize missing data and then adding it to the beginning of the next chunk. Thank you for the information.

Unfortunately nodejs runs out of memory, so I cant really buffer all the data in memory

Comment: @Tweeno - What code are you using for the decoding?  Is is an NPM module?  Or does it have a public repository?